# Changing 'Show Applications' to list view

Tags: screen, display-resolution

I am using Ubuntu on a TV screen but because the resolution is so high, the display is set to zoom 200%.

it works perfectly well for everything apart from 'Show Applications'.  I can only see the icons and not the description.  The simplest way to fix this annoying issue is for me to use list view but I have absolutely no idea how to do it.  Any guidance how this can be changed?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK there is no such option at the moment..

Answer (score 2):

This is a flaw in the current implementation of Application Overview in Gnome Shell, and there is nothing you can do if you are not a programmer. It appears that [this issue is being addressed for Gnome 40](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/01/gnome-shell-show-full-application-name).

You can "workaround" by using a menu system instead to launch applications, such as the "Application menu" extension (part of the "official" extensions, "gnome-shell-extensions") or Arc menu. The former can be installed with `sudo apt get install gnome-shell-extensions`, the latter with `sudo apt get install gnome-shell-extension-arc-menu`.

Comment: May be using GNOME FlashBack is an option.